# Is it possible to create this shape with Border Radius only?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

Consider the following HTML for a tabbed menu:

```
<ul id="nav-tabs">
    <li class="active">Blah</li>
    <li>tab 2</li>
    <li>tab 3</li>
    <li>tab 4</li>
    <li>tab 5</li>
</ul>
```

Not sure if this is doable, but I want to get the shape of the tabs to look like this with border-radius. no images. The top part is easy, but the bottom, how it curves out on the line is the part I don't know if it's possible:

[image]

Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nrmda/)

Comment: It was less than 80%. I just accepted some answers

Comment: See here: http://css-tricks.com/tabs-with-round-out-borders/

Comment: Very cool Joseph. If you want to put that as an answer i'll accept it.

Comment: check this http://css-tricks.com/examples/RoundOutTabs/

Comment: @newuser - That's the demo to the article I linked to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Posting comment as answer...*

Chris Coyier has an article addressing this: [**Tabs with Round Out Borders**](http://css-tricks.com/tabs-with-round-out-borders/).

His implementation is a little different than yours, but by playing with the `border-radius` you should be able to get the effect closer to what you have in your image, though I doubt you'll be able to get the shadow working (if you prove me wrong, post your code here. Would be *very* interesting).